# Link VS 8.0 lib file with VS 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking

I have a quite simple program (Some simple calculations, "give something in, get something out) that I compile to a lib-file using Visual Studio 8.0 SP2.

This lib-file shall be linked into another program. The problem is that the other program is on a computer having Visual Studio 6.0.

When compiling the program and linking in the lib-file (Using VS 6.0) following errors and warnings occur:

First some warnings:

```
    Linking...
myLib.lib(SeController.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
myLib.lib(SeController.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
myLib.lib(SeController.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "alternatename:??$get_name@Vinvalid_argument@std@@@Exception@Impl@Core@@YAPBDXZ=?get_name@Exception@Impl@Core@@YAPBDXZ"; ignored
myLib.lib(SeController.o) : warning LNK4078: multiple ".CRT" sections found with different attributes (40300040)
myLib.lib(bt_errors.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
myLib.lib(bt_errors.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
myLib.lib(SCtrlImpl.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
myLib.lib(SCtrlImpl.o) : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option "manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50608.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b'"; ignored
```

.... (Just some of the warnings here. There are hunders of the same type)

Then (some of) the errors:

```
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char
 const *)" (??4?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV01@PBD@Z) already defined in libcpd.lib(locale0.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) alread
y defined in libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) already defined in
 libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) alread
y defined in libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *,bool)" (??0?$
basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@_N@Z) already defined in libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ) 
already defined in libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP60.dll) : error LNK2005: "protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ) alread
y defined in libcpd.lib(iostream.obj)
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: _vsprintf already defined in libcd.lib(vsprintf.obj)
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in libcd.lib(crt0dat.obj)
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: _atoi already defined in libcd.lib(atox.obj)
```

I have tried to download the Visual Studio 2005 Redistrubate package for VS 8.0 to the computering having 6.0, but I got the same errors and warnings.

Is it even possible to link in a lib-file from 8.0 with a 6.0 compiler?

It is not an option to change the installed versions. (And to not ask why someone are using VS 6.0 :) )

Answer (score 1):

You can link your application against another C runtime, i.e. VS 6.0, but I think that requires both versions to be installed on the same machine. I understood you're talking about different machines, so I assume that's not an option.

If you can create a dynamic library with a plain C API, it would make things a lot easier :) You can use such a DLL from any version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe this text (quoted from [Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MixingCompilers)) then no, you can not -

> Object files and static libraries created with different compilers, or
>   even with significantly different releases of the same compiler, often
>   cannot be linked together. This issue is not specific to MinGW: many
>   other compilers are mutually incompatible. Build everything from
>   source with the same version of the same compiler if you can.
>
> Dll's are slightly different. Sometimes you can link a DLL built with
>   one compiler to an application compiled with another. This works well
>   if the DLL is written in C, even if the application is written in C++.
>   For example, MinGW C++ programs commonly link to the C runtime library
>   provided with Windows. DLLs that are written in C++ work too, as long
>   as you communicate with them only through a C interface declared with
>   extern "C". If you do otherwise, you will probably get linker errors
>   because different compilers mangle C++ names differently.